Detail in the proof of the existence of conditional expectation for L1 random variables in Williams
In the second part of the proof of existence of conditional expectations in Williams (probability with martingales, p. 85, thm 9.2) for $X\in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal A, \mathbb P)$ with respect to subsigma-algebra $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal A$, the author begins with looking at $X^+$. Then, he says one can choose bounded r.v.s $X_0$ with $0\leq X_n\nearrow X$ a.s., and then proceeds with saying that "since $X_n$ are in $L^2$...".
How does this work?
In another proof of the same statement, the $X_n$ are defined as $X_n:=\min(n,X^+)\leq n$. That means $X_n$ ist just cutoff at $n$ and thus
$$\mathbb E[X_n^2]=\int_{\Omega}X_n^2d\mathbb P<n^2\,\mathbb P(X\in[0,n])<\infty.$$
Is that all there's to it?
(Please correct the notation if necessary).
